# Single Instruction Alternates of code snippets

Tags: assembly, x86

What'll be the single Instruction alternates of following code snippets.
I have been trying for hours and can't really figure them out

1. `CMP EBX,EAX
   JNE X1
   MOV EBX,ECX
   JMP X2
   X1: MOV EAX,EBX
   X2`
2. `PUSHF
   MOV BH,FFH
   CMP BL,0
   JL X1
   NOT BH
   X1: POPF`
3. `BT AX,15
   JC X1
   AND EAX,0000FFFFH
   JMP X2
   X1: OR EAX, FFFF0000H
   X2:`


   Please provide an explanation too.

   Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Looks like `cmpxchg ebx, ecx`. `if (eax == ebx) ebx = ecx else eax = ebx`
2. That gives `0FFh` in `bh` if `bl` is negative, or `00h` otherwise. As such that's just sign extending, ie. `movsx bx, bl`
3. That's basically the same, it's sign extending `ax` by testing the sign bit directly, ie. it is `movsx eax, ax`. But note this doesn't affect flags as opposed to the code snippet.

Comment: Can we move into the same register, isn't bl part of bx only?

Comment: Yes, `bl` is part of `bx` and yes, you can sign extend in place.

Comment: Also What is the difference between putting .386 directive before. model tiny declaration and putting
.386 directive after. model tiny declaration?

Comment: For #3, `cwde` is the eax-only short form of `movsx eax, ax`  (@Clarskon: 8086 only had `cbw`, not `movsx/movzx`, so a lot of moving in and out of ax was necessary) .  It doesn't affect flags either, so IDK why #2 saves/restores flags but #3 doesn't.  Well spotted for the `cmpxchg`.  I hadn't ever thought of the fact that it's usable without a memory operand.